# How to import csv file into mysql by phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I am importing Geolite city database in csv format into my phpmyadmin but it only imports first line of it and then saying the "web page not available".

Comment: have you tried doing this directly on mysql console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly load the CSV in mysql using following command:

```
load data local infile 'csvFileName.csv' into table tblUniq fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' (field1, field2, field3)
```

Comment: There is no need to mention thanks, you can show your gratitude on SO by voting up and accepting the answer :)